# VDHX file convert.... A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '1'

Tags: windows, powershell

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Mount-WindowsImage -ImagePath "F:\ed635e4c-450c-4dd9-b34f-2cf209e862b9.vhdx" -Path F:\Mount-Index 1
```

But I get this error:

> Mount-WindowsImage : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '1'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Mount-WindowsImage -ImagePath "F:\ed635e4c-450c-4dd9-b34f-2cf209e862b ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Mount-WindowsImage], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :   PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Dism.Commands.MountWindowsImageCommand

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

This `1` is probably meant to specify the index number, it should be after `-Index`. But you have `F:\Mount-Index` as a single word which is interpreted as the value for preceding `-Path`.

Separate it to `F:\Mount -Index`.